# vector bundles on the affine line over a PID

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, vector-bundles, projective-module

Let $R$ be a PID. Is every finitely generated projective $R[T]$-module free? In other words, is every vector bundle on $\mathbb{A}^1_R$ trivial?

For $R=k[X]$ this is true by the Theorem of Quillen-Suslin. If it fails in general, what happens for $k[X,X^{-1}]$?

Comment: Just one variable (it should stay a PID).

Comment: Quillen-Suslin is for any (PID)$[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

Comment: @QiL: Oh, really? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: See Quillen's Inventiones paper in 1976, Or Ferrand's [Bourbaki talk](http://archive.numdam.org/article/SB_1975-1976__18__202_0.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from Lam's *Serre's problem on projective modules*:

> In 1958, Seshadri showed that Serre's conjecture is true for two variables (i.e. for $A = k[x_1,x_2]$). In fact, Seshadri proved that f.g. projectives over R[t] are free if $R$ is any commutative PID.

Reference: Seshadri, C.S., [*Triviality of vector bundles over the affine space* $K^2$](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC335443/pdf/pnas00684-0093.pdf), Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA **44**, 456-458.

Comment: As the answer is entirely included in that Seshadri's article, I realise I should delete any reference to Lam's book. But this book is so wonderful (as is anything written by Lam) I won't do so.

Comment: Why is it enough to prove the case n=2 in Proposition 1?